# angular not showing default text box value when i use [ngModel]

Tags: angular

I am using Angular version 6.
When I run the below code it works

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="designation" value="sample"   />
```

I need to get this default value ("sample") from text box, so then I changed this code to

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="designation" value="sample" [(ngModel)]="addRequisitionss.designation"  name="designation" #designation="ngModel"  />
```

When I executed above code value "sample" is not showing in text box.

I am trying to display default value("sample") in the text field, and I have to fetch that value("sample"), any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have `ngModel` on an input tag, it takes preference over the `value` attribute. So it is good to initialise value with `ngModel` variable itself.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="designation" [(ngModel)]="addRequisitionss.designation"  
 name="designation" #designation="ngModel"  />
```

ts code :

```
addRequisitionss.designation = 'sample';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make the default value like that:

component.html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="designation [(ngModel)]="addRequisitionss.designation"  name="designation" />
```

and in component.ts make the dafault value

```
addRequisitionss.designation = "default value"
```